# Finding ending bracket for opening bracket, but exact matching closing bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't know how to explain this without showing this javascript code, so here it is:

```
syntax="{middle/point/{??/midpoint-x/(;start;)/(;end;)}:{??/midpoint-y/(;start;)/(;end;)}}";
syntax_e=syntax.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/gim,function($1){alert($1);});
alert(syntax_e);
```

Input:

> {middle/point/{??/midpoint-x/(;start;)/(;end;)}:{??/midpoint-y/(;start;)/(;end;)}}

Expected outputs:

```
> middle/point/{??/midpoint-x/(;start;)/(;end;)}:{??/midpoint-y/(;start;)/(;end;)}

> ??/midpoint-x/(;start;)/(;end;)
```

and

```
> ??/midpoint-y/(;start;)/(;end;)
```

Resulting output:

> middle/point/{??/midpoint-x/(;start;)/(;end;)

That and a few others that shouldn't be as they are.
Where it isn't stopping at it's matching ending bracket.

This is for an app where you type in commands like this, and a graphing calculator of course processes and executes each command within { and }, one after another, and when it comes to a command with more brackets/commands in it, it is supposed to evaluate it first then return the value, as specified by the $ mark which means return value. But without this I can't get anything done, otherwise I will have to do it a more longer and way that is not useful for people less knowledgable to computers or programming/scripting.

Live example : http://jstone88.bugs3.com/desmos
It will execute a few alerts with the unneeded results.

I am sorry if I wasted time and there is already a given answer to this, it's difficult sometimes for me to get the correct wording in the search.

Comment: You should look for a full-blown parser (there are easy to use parser generators). [JavaScript] Regex is not capable of matching arbitrarily nested parentheses.

Comment: Do you know any? Or how I should word it in google search?

Comment: Parsers are domain specific -- you may find out that you have to write your own.  However, most parsers are fairly easy.. but @Bergi is right. Regex is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Yes, googling for "javascript parser generator" should come up with some useful results.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks I'll go with PEG.js, now is there like a tutorial reference I can use to learn how to create syntax for my specified use?

Comment: You don't even need a script/program for this. You can see matching brackets in any editor like Notepad++ or Sublime Text. It will save you tons of time if you are only needing to find the sets of brackets. However, your question is *very* unclear.

Comment: @Signus I'm using matchRecursive by http://blog.stevenlevithan.com

Comment: @ModerateJavaScriptDev If you found a solution, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matchRecursive found at blog.stevenlevithan.com